# WAN fails but only some sites

Tags: networking, router, dns, dig

Home network, xfinity. I’ve had intermittent outages for the last two weeks. After some back and forth with xfinity, I bought a new cable modem. I spent an hour with support yesterday, then sent the “magic packets” to the modem and claim it’s working fine.

This morning I’m seeing weird behavior I’m not sure how to explain.

Set up:

Alternating Mac and Linux computers hard wired to the modem, manual ip’s set in both.

I can access the modem’s management page, everything looks fine, exception SYNC errors in error log.

Multiple browsers: chrome, Firefox, Brave

I can reach some sites, but not others. For example:

[www.xfinity.com](http://www.xfinity.com) yes, xfinity.com no.
Some redirects do work: Google.com redirects to the www site.

I’m also seeing occasional “snap this webpage crashed” messages.

This is one of those: it’s probably DNS issues, but I’m not sure where the issue might be, and if I should I push harder on xfinity, or do more digging myself.

I’m skipping the router to narrow down the issues, but things seems even more broken there.

Comment: Do you have an IPv4 address? What happens if you _do not_ use manual IP configuration?

Comment: Well that seems to have fixed the issue. Any explanation as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [www.xfinity.com](http://www.xfinity.com) yes, xfinity.com no.

The difference between the two is that `www.xfinity.com` has an **IPv6** address (`AAAA` DNS record), while `xfinity.com` doesn't. (The former is hosted at Akamai CDN, the latter is a smaller redirect-only server run by Comcast themselves.)

Your machines had working IPv6 automatically configured, but your manual IPv4 configuration was wrong, so they could access websites that have IPv6 but not the ones that don't. (My wild guess is that you tried to use the modem as the gateway while it is not set up as a router – it is likely *just* a bridge modem that connects you to a remote router.)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I now have an IPv6 address as my public address as well.