# How to get ip address from Modem to Router

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, modem

I've been having network failures, possibly a variety of sources, but I've now narrowed it down to the "connection" between my Ubiquiti Edgerouter X and the Arris Modem. (for Modem to internet problems, check out [WAN fails but only some sites](https://superuser.com/questions/1806731/wan-fails-but-only-some-sites), IPv6 confusion on my part).

I have confirmed that I can connect to the internet from at least one machine by connecting directly to the modem with an ethernet cable, and setting Ipv4 to automatic(DHCP), IPv6 to automatic. (This is through Ubuntu's wired settings GUI interface).

However, it appears that the router isn't getting an ip address from the Modem (or ISP, I'm not sure). I ran through the Basic Wizard setup in Edgerouter, which turns off dnsmasq, set's it's subnet to `192.168.1.0/24` and sets some other basic configuration*.

The primary dashboard shows a status of connected, but doesn't display an ipAddress, and the Tx rates are mostly 0, the Rx rates low. When I try to ping anything from inside the Edgerouter I get `Temporary failure in name resolution`. I can't reach any sites from the computer connected to the router.

I have swapped out the cable between the router and modem.

I'm not sure what other steps to take to debug the issue.

*There is a ipv6 firewall configured be default: WANv6_IN -> rule 10: accept; rule 20 drop;
and WANv6_LOCAL -> rule 10: accept; 20: drop; 30: accept; 40 accept;

Comment: Add the interfaces part of your config? Try and reboot the modem before connecting the router - some ISPs are picky about how many/how often devices request an IP. The router should log its DHCP requests somewhere, especially if it's failing